# Hacer boolean sinónimo de booleano

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Las siguientes etiquetas una es el término en inglés y la otra el término en español.

Favor de hacer el término en inglés sinónimo del término en español.

[booleano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/booleano) ← [boolean](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boolean)

Comment: Ya ha sido creado el sinónimo. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b Mil gracias.